# Why can't I get a delay between two audio files

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to delay only ONE of the two input files. But, even with a value of 5, itsoffset is not working....why??

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 5 -i one.m4a -i five.m4a -strict -2 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[aout]" -map "[aout]" out.m4a
```

---

```
 ffmpeg version 2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Jul 16 2014 21:03:06 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
      configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/tempdisk/sw --as=yasm --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib --enable-avfilter --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libass --enable-libutvideo --enable-filters --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect
      libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
      libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
      libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
      libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
      libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
      libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
      libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
      libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'one.m4a':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : M4A 
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
      Duration: 00:00:04.41, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 153 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 149 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'five.m4a':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : M4A 
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
      Duration: 00:00:04.41, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 151 kb/s
        Stream #1:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 147 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    [Parsed_pan_1 @ 0x7f8f63d038e0] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items.
    [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7f8f63d035a0] No channel layout for input 1
    [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7f8f63d035a0] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
    Output #0, ipod, to 'o.m4a':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : M4A 
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2
        encoder         : Lavf55.48.100
        Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc55.69.100 aac
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 (aac) -> amerge:in0
      Stream #1:0 (aac) -> amerge:in1
      pan -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    size=      70kB time=00:00:06.41 bitrate=  89.7kbits/s    
    video:0kB audio:69kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.148568%
```

Comment: Have you investigated the [`adelay` audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay)?